# Is there any global() function?

Tags: vimscript, command-line

I searched a little for a `global` function that would act as the `:g` command but in a more Function-style.

Like the substitute command which has a function associated :

```
:h substitute()
:h :substitute
```

Do you know if such exists ?

Comment: `substitute()` acts on a string - are you looking for a `global()` function that acts on a string? If not, you are not looking for a `:g` equivalent in the same way `substitute()` is associated with `:substitute`.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're looking for, but `:help function-list` will show you all the built-in functions with short descriptions and should help you find something that meets your needs. Also, it's common in scripts to put a while loop around a call to search() and then perform the desired editing operation (e.g., substitute()) on the lines found.

Comment: @VanLaser : yes exactly

Comment: @garyjohn : I know, that is where I searched for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no such function and it would not make much sense. If you need to do something for each item in a list, you can loop around it.